# Trying to find a solution to distinguishing between the different appearances of values?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Here's the function I'm trying to create,

```
def compile_italics(line):
```

It's a markdown to HTML compiler

If the line input is

```
compile_italics('*italic* not italic.')
```

I need to find a way to replace every `*` with `<i>` and `</i>` respectively. Problem is, I don't know how to distinguish between the first and second `*`.

Ideally, the output should be:

```
'<i>italic</i> not italic.'
```

Other examples:

```
compile_italic('*italic*')
>>>'<i>italic</i>'

compile_italic('this is *italic*!')
>>> 'this is <i>italic</i>!'

compile_italic_star('*italic*, and *italic*!')
>>> '<i>italic</i>, and <i>italic</i>!'

compile_italic_star('not *italic')
>>> not *italic'
```

Comment: It depends on how you're parsing this, but you could have a flag `found_start = False`. If you find a star and that flag is `False`, you know it's the first star, and then you set the flag to `True`. If you find a star and the flag is `True`, then you know that that's the second star.

Comment: There are many ways to attack this problem, depending on how sophisticated you want to be.  The first step is to be able to describe in words how you'd distinguish between the first and second `*`.  Do they always appear on the same line?  Is there a chance that you would want a `*` to be part of the text to be displayed instead of meaning the start or end of italics, and how would you know the difference?  Unless you can describe the process to yourself, you can't describe it to a computer.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, a regular expression is a viable option. That kind of replacement can be achieved using a function as replace argument of the `re.sub` method:

```py
import re


def replace(match):
    match1 = match.group(1)
    return f"<i>{match1}</i>"

your_string = "*example* hello *example2*"

result = re.sub(r"\*([^\*]+)\*", replace, your_string)

print(result)

# <i>example</i> hello <i>example2</i>

result = re.sub(r"\*([^\*]+)\*", replace, "*italic*, and not *italic")

print(result)

# <i>italic</i>, and not *italic
```

The parts of the regular expression:

- `\*` - a star (the first)
- `([^\*]+)` - any number of characters that are not star, grouped
- `\*` - another star (the second one that closes the pattern)

If you want to handle double stars to support **bold**, then you might handle first this pattern: `r"\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*"`, and then this pattern: `r"\*([^\*]+)\*"`.